# Grouping within a While Loop, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, grouping

I've been building a while loop to populate a lot of data, and I'm struggling with grouping within the query - I want to add a group on Membership_Level but each time it is returning identical values (the total) for each Level.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!!!

```
DECLARE @Counter int
DECLARE @NumPerson int

SET @Counter = 1

WHILE @Counter <= 12

BEGIN
    SET @NumPerson = (SELECT
    SUM(Amount)
    FROM [NewMember]
    WHERE LEFT([PERIOD], 4) = 2016
    AND GRADE_STATUS = 'N'
    AND RIGHT([Period], 2) = @Counter)

    SELECT
    *
    FROM (SELECT
    CAST(@NumPerson AS varchar(6)) AS 'Number',
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(CAST(@Counter AS varchar(2))) = 1 THEN '0' + CAST(@Counter AS varchar(2))
        ELSE CAST(@Counter AS varchar(2))
    END AS 'Month') s
    JOIN (SELECT
    MAX('1') AS NGroup,
    [PERIOD],
    RIGHT([Period], 2) AS 'Month',
    MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL
    FROM [NewMember]
    WHERE LEFT([PERIOD], 4) = 2016
    AND GRADE_STATUS = 'N'
    GROUP BY    [MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL],
                [PERIOD],
                RIGHT([Period], 2)) t
    ON s.[Month] = t.[Month]
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

Comment: You have some issues here. First is using a loop when you don't need one. It will always return the same data because your query is always going to get the same rows. We can help but we need some details to work with. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: maybe if you provide sample data and desired outcome you could get better help

Comment: To expand on @SeanLange 's comment The variables that change `@Counter`  and `@NumPerson`  are not included in the inner query/inline view that contain the group by clause so it won't change. Perhaps if you add `AND Month(Period) = @Counter` to the where clause there.

Comment: What is your input and expected output? Do you really require looping?